# When using VideoWriter in opencv-python the output video length is 0

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, video-processing

I'm trying to read a video, put some shapes on it and write it out using opencv-python (using `VideoWriter` class):

```
def Mask_info(path):
    """This function will mask the information part of the video"""
    video = cv.VideoCapture(path)
    framenum = video.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    fps = video.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"vp09")
    width = int(video.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    height = int(video.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    size = (width,height)
    
    if (video.isOpened ==False ):
        print("Error while reading the file.")
    
    result = cv.VideoWriter("masked_video.mp4",fourcc,fps,size)

    while(True):

        isTrue,frame = video.read()

        cv.rectangle(frame,(65,0),(255,10),(0,0,0),-1)
        cv.rectangle(frame,(394,0),(571,10),(0,0,0),-1)

        if isTrue == True:
            result.write(frame)
            cv.imshow("Masked Video",frame)

            if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("d"):
                break
        else:
            break 


    video.release()
    result.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

    
Mask_info("samplesound.webm")
```

The problem is that the output video length is zero, while the input video is 10 seconds.

Comment: (1) Did you verify `video.read()` returns some valid frames ? (2) In any case the drawing of rectangles should be done inside `if isTrue == True:`.

Comment: Wohlstad is correct, the reason that it's not working is that the `cv.rectangle` executions are before `if isTrue == True` (they should be inside the `if`). When `isTrue` = `False`, the value of `frame` is `None`, and there is an exception... The code never reaches `result.release()`, and the video length is zero because the file is not closed. For testing, you may also try replacing `*"vp09"` with `*"mp4v"`.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks for your answer I will reply and explain the first thing which wohlstad said in his answer. About the mp4v, I tried it but because the input video format is webm it will not respond correctly and I was forced to use vp09.

Comment: @keibodnouripour Your output file is MP4: `result = cv.VideoWriter("masked_video.mp4")`. I recommend you to use the debugger and step through your code, watching values and the behavior while debugging. If you are not using an IDE, I recommend using [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Comment: @Rotem I'm using vscode and I will try your solution thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment above:

1. You should verify that `video.read()` returns any valid  frame.
   It could be that due to path or other issue the `VideoCapture` failed to open the input file.
2. You attempt to draw the rectangles (using `cv.rectangle`) before the `if` that checks whether you have a valid frame.
   But if `video.read()` failed (e.g. when reaching the end of the input) `frame` will be `None`. Then `cv.rectangle` will throw an exception causing the program to terminate without flushing and closing the output file.
   Instead you should do the drawings inside the `isTrue == True` branch of the `if`:

```
if isTrue == True:
    cv.rectangle(frame,(65,0),(255,10),(0,0,0),-1)
    cv.rectangle(frame,(394,0),(571,10),(0,0,0),-1)
    result.write(frame)
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your direct and complete instructions. I tested video.read() and it was not empty. I even put the rectangle codes inside if isTrue == True as you said, but it still gives me a standstill video with 0 lengths.

Comment: Do you see any error / exception message ? Also how many frames do you succeed to get from `video.read()` ? You can add a counter and print it for every frame.

Comment: No errors all clear. I did not get any frames, I stored video.read() as a variable and printed it. Got arrays with uint8 dtype.

Comment: What do you mean by _"I did not get any frames"_ ? The first time you call `video.read()` you get `isTrue==False`  (and `frame == None`) ?

Comment: BTW - frame data can be represented indeed by arrays with uint8 elements. It contains RGB 0..255 for each pixel (or gray level 0..255 for grayscale images).

Comment: When I run the code nothing comes into my terminal. The only way which came to my mind to check if the frame was not empty or False is to save it as a variable and print it. Accordingly, I got arrays so I don't think its False.

Comment: I got frames as an array

Comment: You can use `print(isTrue)` to make sure. Similarly you can add a counter of frames, increment it for each frame you get with `isTrue==true` and print it every frame.

Comment: Thanks. But do you think this will help to get the output video fixed?

Comment: First you need to make sure you have valid input frames. After you confirmed this, you should address the output. E.g. maybe you don't have permission to write the output file ? Maybe try to a different path ? But this is useful only after you made sure you have input frames.